# Can we implement Sass in Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, sass, less, frontend, semantic-ui

Regarding Semantic UI and Sass, as stated in [Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/ham3gg/move-over-bootstrap-and-foundation-welcome-semantic-ui); Notable drawbacks of Semantic UI is stated as

```
Some Cons
1. No image slider
2. No thumbnail classes
3. No visibility classes
4. No SASS (does have LESS)
5. Not at a release >1.0
```

Can we really not implement Sass in latest Semantic UI version?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to achieve this using npm Library.**(semantic-ui-sass)**

> npm i semantic-ui-sass

For better understanding please follow the below reference:-
[semanti-ui-sass.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui-sass)